# "network paradigm" or "networking paradigm"

Tags: word-choice

I want to know which one is correct:

> A novel network paradigm

or

> A novel networking paradigm

If both of them are correct, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Some context would be useful.  Are you talking about network design in computing?  Networking as social connections?

Comment: @AmaiKotori I'm talking about network design. I want to introduce IoT as a novel paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

Both are usable; for your given example of the IoT, **network** is probably the better match, suggesting the structure of the network rather than the process of working with it or the protocols used for communication.